# Setting RunWorkerCompleted value

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

If i have a background worker that does some tasks in its do work

```
    String val= getVal("Val");
    byte[] b = (byte[])e.Argument;

    b = getData.FromPlace(val);
```

How do i pass the vakue of b to the runworkercompleted method?

Answer (score 4):

You could use closure

```
void Main()
{

    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    byte[] b;

    bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => {

        b = DoStuff();
    };
}

byte[] DoStuff() {

    String val= getVal("Val");
    byte[] b = (byte[])e.Argument;

    b = getData.FromPlace(val);

    return b;
}
```

You could also use return Result property on the event args object. I think this way gives more flexibility.

```
void Main()
{
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => {

        args.Result = DoStuff();
    };

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>  {
        var result = args.Result as byte[];
    };

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

byte[] DoStuff() {
    return new byte[10];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an instance variable. Place the declaration above the `DoWork` event definition.

```
private byte[] b;
```