# BackgroundWorker ReportProgress from Different Class

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp, backgroundworker

I'm going in circles searching and reading forums on how to solve this problems. After a day of trying I'm still at a loss how to solve my problem. I'm uploading a file and need to return the % in a a textbox. I'm having no problem with the upload portion and have no problems returning the values using the BackgroundWorker if I include all my code within the same class. However, what I'm doing is calling an ftp class from form1. I need the ftp class to return the percentage to form1 so I can can display in my UI and also need to have the server response codes returned from my ftp class to display in my form1. Everything was working ok before I tried to run this in a BackgroundWorker process, with the exception of course that the UI becomes unresponsive and returns all status messages after upload completed. Heres my code as it stands now. How do I get the percentage from ftp class and pass it back to form1, as well as the server response code once completed?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private string ftpServer = @"ftp://10.0.0.0";
    private string ftpUser = @"user";
    private string ftpPass = @"pass";
    private string ftpRemoteFile = @"myfile.exe";
    private string ftpLocalFile = @"C:\Uploads\file.exe";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressRichTextBox.Text = "Sending";
        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        ftp ftpClient = new ftp(ftpServer, ftpUser, ftpPass);
        ftpClient.upload(progressRichTextBox, ftpRemoteFile, ftpLocalFile);
    }
    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            this.progressRichTextBox.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        }

        else
        {
            this.progressRichTextBox.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressRichTextBox.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }
}
```

And heres the ftp class:

```
    public void upload(System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox progressRichTextBox, string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localFile);
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* Specify generic group name for faster upload */
        ftpRequest.ConnectionGroupName = "AffiliateUpload";
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        /* Server connection options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpRequest.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;
        /* Buffer for the Data */
        byte[] buff = new byte[bufferSize];
        int contentLen;
        /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
        FileStream localFileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

        try
        {
            // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
            ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

            // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
            contentLen = localFileStream.Read(buff, 0, bufferSize);

            // Till Stream content ends
            while (contentLen != 0)
            {
                // Write Content from the file stream to the 
                // FTP Upload Stream
                ftpStream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                contentLen = localFileStream.Read(buff, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
            ftpStream.Close();
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed sending to " + host + "/" + remoteFile + " (" + ex.Message + ")");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think what's happening here is you're trying to call the main UI thread from a background thread (ftp class).  You need to have the ftp class call the delegate method ProgressChanged and update the progress that way

Comment: Take a look at [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I strongly suggest that you try using Tasks if you can. You can use them even if you are not able to migrate to .Net 4.5 by using [the BCL package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/1.1.8). It supports a much cleaner progress model than the one used by Backgroundworker. [This](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html) is a very good comparison between them.

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 so the BCL package isn't an option for me at this point still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to update `progressRichTextBox` in your upload method. Remove that parameter. You need to provide the `worker` object to your upload method and call `worker.ReportProgress` on it.

Comment: Thanks that solved half of my problem so I can return the % completed now. The second half of my issue is that I need to return the server response code when an exception is returned as in my catch method of ftp class. In form1 I do have logic for RunWorkerCompleted but I'm not sure how to pass anything back upon Error. If successful completion I see the "Done!" message but I never see the "Error:" message. What am I missing for that piece?

Comment: Check out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499657/setting-runworkercompleted-value

Comment: Thanks for response. To return a string I ended up using UserState instead of what was listed on that link. I had a couple places where I needed to return a value to my UI in the middle of my DoWork so there I used Invoke. All seems to be working now.